# Turn Location on or off / or opining Location settings in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, permissions

Issue using Xamarin forms ,

I am trying to find a way to prompt the user to switch location on either by going directly to the settings or just tapping "yes" on the screen.

I tried  a lot of code , can anyone help with this issue in a clear and working code??

Thanks.

Comment: use [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android).  It will prompt the user to allow Location access - if they do not, all you can do is prompt them to enable it in settings.

Comment: You can't change the system setting directly. You can navigate user to the system setting page instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot do such a thing.
At best, you can ask why you want your authorization in a popup.
If the user agrees to give permission, you can request authorization.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == global::Xamarin.Forms.Device.Android)
                    {
                        var result = await DisplayAlert("Turn Off Gps", "Please Turn On Gps  ,\n Do you want to go to Settings ? ", "Yes", "No");
                        if (result == true)
                        {
                            global::Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<global::SmartCube.Model.ILocSettings>().OpenSettings();
                            
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Turn Off Gps", "Please Turn On Gps for Location", "Ok");
                    }
```